# Vpd r/w failed This is likely a firmware bug on this device

Tags: linux, raid, hardware, hardware-raid, firmware

Does this mean my RAID 1 device is failing?

EDIT: seeing this is a raidcare issue. How can I pull the specs and download/install the driver?

```
netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
netlink: 12 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
megaraid_sas 0000:05:00.0: vpd r/w failed.  This is likely a firmware bug on
```

Comment: No. This means what is repeated over and over in these messages. Read it. Do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the *rest* of the message.

> ```
> Contact the card vendor for a firmware update.
> ```

So your RAID controller card is what you want to look at.